# How to remove the associated UIProgressview with the right request?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, asihttprequest, uiprogressview

I use asihttprequest to download multiple files and I'm wondering how I can remove the associated UIProgressview with the right request when the download is done.

`NSMutableArray *contentArray` contains the `ASIHTTPRequest` and `NSMutableArray *progArray` contains my custom UIProgressview.

```
-(void)addDownload:(NSString *)theURL withName:(NSString *)fileName
{
theProgress = [[PDColoredProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 17, 314, 14)];
//...
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
//..
[request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:theProgress];
    request.allowResumeForFileDownloads = YES;
    [request startAsynchronous];
    [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
    [contentArray addObject:request];
    [progArray addObject:theProgress];
    [theProgress retain];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

        [contentArray removeObject:request]; 
        [progArray removeObject:theProgress]; 
        NSLog(@"%@",progArray);
        NSLog(@"%@",contentArray);
        [self reloadMyData]; 
        [self.tableView reloadData]; 


        }
```

The problem is that this code remove the last progressview even if the there are 3 downloads in `contentArray` and the second one finish first.
Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove progress view that's associated with finished request you can get it from request's `downloadProgressDelegate` property:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

    PDColoredProgressView *progress = (PDColoredProgressView*)request.downloadProgressDelegate;
    [contentArray removeObject:request]; 
    if (progress)
       [progArray removeObject:progress]; 
    [self reloadMyData]; 
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```